# Dynamic changing of the text color of Toolbar MenuItem text

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar

In the app I am working on colors for various UI elements come from an HTTP response, ie coloring is done at *runtime*, and cannot be done using Android theming.

Other questions exist on this topic, but most are using themes, or if dynamic code, the code is not working. For example using spans:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menuItemGoalSave = menu.findItem(R.id.action_goal_edit_save);
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(menuItemGoalSave.getTitle() + "XX");
    ForegroundColorSpan span = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
    s.setSpan(span, 0, s.length(), 0);
    menuItemGoalSave.setTitle(s);
    return true;
}
```

Or similar approaches applying HTML strings.

The code above in theory applies a span with coloring, but although the title has "XX" appended (ie the code is running, and affecting the menu item) the colour does not change.

Is there any way to dynamically affect the color of this Toolbar action item text?

Comment: Please clarify at what moment you're setting new color

Comment: I have flexibility, but currently am trying to do it in onPrepareOptionsMenu()

Answer (score 2):

## Updated

Also it works as expected in case if you're using 'Toolbar' directly. See example

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
        mToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    }

    private void applyMenuItemTextColor() {
        MenuItem item = mToolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_settings);
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString(item.getTitle());
        ForegroundColorSpan span = new ForegroundColorSpan(System.currentTimeMillis() % 2 == 0 ? Color.RED :Color.GREEN);
        s.setSpan(span, 0, s.length(), 0);
        item.setTitle(s);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            applyMenuItemTextColor();//supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

## Original answer

Your spans example works as expected. See results:

[image]

[image]

Here's code used for this sample:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString(item.getTitle());
        ForegroundColorSpan span = new ForegroundColorSpan(System.currentTimeMillis() % 2 == 0 ? Color.RED :Color.GREEN);
        s.setSpan(span, 0, s.length(), 0);
        item.setTitle(s);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I hope this will be helpful. Please let me know if there are any questions.

Comment: I've carefully compared my code with yours line by line, and as far as I can see they are identical. I've expanded the code sample in my original question, pasting it from my source. I've tried many variants of the code and have yet to see it work. I've tested it on N (emulated), Lollipop and Marshamallow. My activity also inherits from AppCompatActivity. Clearly I'm missing something, but I have no idea what.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TextView liveitem = (TextView )mOptionsMenu.findItem(R.id.action_live);
liveitem.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: I am using the support library, and cannot cast the MenuItem to TextView (or AppCompatTextView), at least in onPrepareOptionsMenu(): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView  Or perhaps the cast might work at a different point in the Activity lifecycle?